# Python decode() cannot decode google's index page?

Tags: python, sockets, utf-8

I'm currently trying to implement a "Get web page from the source and store it as files in local directory" application, and I'm in a lot of trouble...

One of my problem is, I tried to contact google with a GET request, receive the html file and store it in a local directory. Here's my complete code for this part of the program:

```
from socket import *
import sys

SN = "www.google.com"
SP = 80

Csocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
Csocket.connect((SN, SP))
Header = 'GET /' +""+ ' HTTP/1.1\r\n' + "Host: " + "www.google.com\r\n" + "Connection: close\r\n" + 
"Accept-language: us-en\r\n" + "Cache-Control: public\r\n\r\n"

Csocket.send(Header.encode())
result = Csocket.recv(999999) .decode('UTF-8')#.split("\r\n\r\n", 1)[1]  
fn = "Google"+".html"
file = open(fn, 'a')
file.write(result)
print(result)
```

It seems to work, I get the 200 OK html respond. but when I try to decode the respond from google server with the `.decode()` function, I got an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/artha/PycharmProjects/WEEEB/venv/Client.py", line 11, in <module>
result = Csocket.recv(999999) .decode('UTF-8').split("\r\n\r\n", 1)[1]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 45407: invalid start byte
```

I then switch to `.decode(utf-16)`, and it was the same story

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x3e in position 47770: truncated data
```

Honestly I have no Idea what's going on here, please help me out! Thank you.

BTW, do anyone know how to set a "dynamic" `socket.recv()` buffer size? there's big website and there's small website. Thus, I'm forced to set the buffer size super large so I won't miss anything. Could anyone please tell me how do I let the program adjust the buffer size to fit the incoming data? thank you very much!

Comment: Works for me. But I would wager that you're getting responses with charsets other than what you're hard-coding into your script. You should parse the response headers and use the charset header instead. That, or use one of the _many_ HTTP client libraries that already exist and already solve this and many other problems, eg: arbitrary-length responses, buffering, redirects, etc.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're not using something like Requests or even urllib, instead of sockets? Also, `import *` is generally bad practice.

Comment: Note: `file = open(fn, 'a')` doesn't define an encoding: please write it explicitly (also because Windows is still a special case). This is not the cause of the previous error. Add on decode an error behaviour (e.g. escape), and try to find which character is escaped, and why.